# Meaning: "So, too is (that)"

Tags: meaning, grammar, meaning-in-context, syntactic-analysis

What does the beginning of the sentence mean? It is my first encounter with a "**So, too is (that)**" structure. I would gladly learn what it means and how it is grammatically constructed alike.

> In that photo (which may have been taken in Paris) the baron holds a cigarette or, more likely, a joint up to the parted lips of Ms. Mitchell, who looks fully zonked. Weed references are always relevant when characterizing Los Angeles, or, anyway, certain of its West side ZIP codes. **So, too is that** admixture of high glamour and drawstring comfort that defines the actual relationship between Hollywood and fashion.
>   [*New York Times*, "Tom Ford’s ‘Very L.A.’ Show," 9 Feb. 2020](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/02/09/style/tom-ford-fall-2020-los-angeles.html)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Weed references are relevant. So too (also relevant) is that admixture of...

Comment: So could I for instance write the following:
"This woman is elegantly dressed. So, too is he."

I'd presume it retains the same structure & meaning alike.

Comment: "So too" essentially means likewise here.  I think the comma may be a typographical error.  See, for example [Just as ...  so too ...](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/just-as-so-too).

Comment: @user208726 Thank you so much. When you say "here", do you have any other example in mind where it could be used differently ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  "So too" essentially means likewise.  It is more commonly used in British English rather than American English.  I used the word "here" simply to relate it to its general usage.

Comment: Very well, thank you so much !

Comment: To me, having one comma seems odd. "So, too, is that" fits better into my idiolect - the "too" is acting sort of parenthetically.

Comment: @user888379 From what I could find upon the internet, it seems like the "too" is here just to lay emphasis. Do you know a sentence wherein the too would be mandatory for it to make sense ?

Comment: @Romain I can't think of one, but I wouldn't be so foolhardy as to claim there isn't such a sentence.

Comment: 'So, too, is X' or 'So too is X' is essentially just a re-ordering of 'X is, too.'